# Same code in C++ and Python calculates diff values after a lot of loops, is it the nature of float/double?

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, floating-point

I am writing a driver model using C++ and Python to compare the performance.
The simulation gives data like width, position, speed, etc. and the driver model does some calculations to decide if it needs to brake or not.
Both models have the same variables and calculations, but after looping over 500 times first divergence surface and in the end, result in different brake responses. I am aware that floating point error is a thing, but shouldn't it be the same for both languages?
I checked C++ and Python if they have IEEE 754 and it seems to be the case. I will attach my check at the end of the question.

Is there something I don't know about float calculations or I do sth wrong in my codes?

What did I expect: That I get the same response for both driver models.

C++ Code:

> 

```
void DM::runAccumulator()
{    // storing values from previous run
    double prevVTheta = vTheta;
    double prevVActivation = vActivation;

    // shorter handle for convinience and to stay true to given Modell
    double egoSpeed    = data.egoSpeed;
    double egoAcc      = data.egoAcc;
    double egoLength = data.egoLength;
    double targetSpeed = data.targetSpeed;
    double targetAcc   = data.targetAcc;
    double targetWidth = data.targetWidth;
    double targetLength = data.targetLength;
    
    // calculate positional data
    double targetPosRear = data.targetPosX - targetLength/2.0;
    double egoPosFront = data.egoPosX + egoLength/2.0;
    double distEgotoTarget = targetPosRear - egoPosFront;

    // optical size of target vehicle
    vTheta = 2.0 * std::atan(targetWidth / (2.0 * prevDistEgoToTarget));
    prevDistEgoToTarget = distEgotoTarget;
    vThetaDot = (vTheta - prevVTheta)/timestep;
    vp = vThetaDot/vTheta;
   
    if (log = true)
    {
        this -> file << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << data.timestamp << ',' << std::setprecision(6) << targetPosRear << ',' << egoPosFront << ',' << prevDistEgoToTarget << ',' << vTheta << ',' << vThetaDot << ',' << vp << '\n';

    }
```

Python:

> 

```
def runAccumulator(self):
        #storing values from previous run
        prevVTheta = self.vTheta
        prevVActivation = self.vActivation

        #shorter handle for convinience and to stay true to given Modell
        egoSpeed    = self.data.egoSpeed
        egoAcc      = self.data.egoAcc
        egoLength = self.data.egoLength
        targetSpeed = self.data.targetSpeed
        targetAcc   = self.data.targetAcc
        targetWidth = self.data.targetWidth
        targetLength = self.data.targetLength

        # calculate positional data
        targetPosRear = self.data.targetPosX - targetLength/2.0
        egoPosFront = self.data.egoPosX + egoLength/2.0
        distEgotoTarget = targetPosRear - egoPosFront

        # optical size target vehicle and looming
        self.vTheta = 2.0*arctan(targetWidth/(2.0*self.prevDistEgoToTarget))
        self.prevDistEgoToTarget = distEgotoTarget
        self.vThetaDot = (self.vTheta - prevVTheta)/self.timestep
        self.vp = self.vThetaDot/self.vTheta

        # Driver Model update
        self.vEpsilon = self.vp - self.vpp 
        activationChange = (self.accuK * self.vEpsilon - self.accuM - self.accuC * prevVActivation) * self.timestep
        self.vActivation = max(0.0, prevVActivation-activationChange)


        # log some parameters
        if self.log == True:
            logString = str(self.data.timestamp) + ','
            logString += str(targetPosRear) + ',' #'{:.7f}'.format(targetPosRear) + ','
            logString += str(egoPosFront) + ',' #'{:.7f}'.format(egoPosFront) + ','
            logString += str(self.prevDistEgoToTarget) + ',' #'{:.7f}'.format(targetPosRear - egoPosFront) + ',';
            logString += str(self.vTheta) + ',' #'{:.7f}'.format(self.vTheta) + ',' 
            logString +=str(self.vThetaDot) + ',' # '{:.7f}'.format(self.vThetaDot) + ','
            logString += str(self.vp) + '\n' #'{:.7f}'.format(self.vp) + '\n'
            self.file.write(logString)
```

C++ IEEE 754 Check:

> 

```
#include <cfloat>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
 
int main()
{
    int w = 16;
    std::cout << std::left; // std::cout << std::setprecision(53);
#   define COUT(x) std::cout << std::setw(w) << #x << " = " << x << '\n'
 
    COUT( FLT_RADIX        );
    COUT( DECIMAL_DIG      );
    COUT( FLT_DECIMAL_DIG  );
    COUT( DBL_DECIMAL_DIG  );
    COUT( LDBL_DECIMAL_DIG );
    COUT( FLT_MIN          );
    COUT( DBL_MIN          );
    COUT( LDBL_MIN         );
    COUT( FLT_TRUE_MIN     );
    COUT( DBL_TRUE_MIN     );
    COUT( LDBL_TRUE_MIN    );
    COUT( FLT_MAX          );
    COUT( DBL_MAX          );
    COUT( LDBL_MAX         );
    COUT( FLT_EPSILON      );
    COUT( DBL_EPSILON      );
    COUT( LDBL_EPSILON     );
    COUT( FLT_DIG          );
    COUT( DBL_DIG          );
    COUT( LDBL_DIG         );
    COUT( FLT_MANT_DIG     );
    COUT( DBL_MANT_DIG     );
    COUT( LDBL_MANT_DIG    );
    COUT( FLT_MIN_EXP      );
    COUT( DBL_MIN_EXP      );
    COUT( LDBL_MIN_EXP     );
    COUT( FLT_MIN_10_EXP   );
    COUT( DBL_MIN_10_EXP   );
    COUT( LDBL_MIN_10_EXP  );
    COUT( FLT_MAX_EXP      );
    COUT( DBL_MAX_EXP      );
    COUT( LDBL_MAX_EXP     );
    COUT( FLT_MAX_10_EXP   );
    COUT( DBL_MAX_10_EXP   );
    COUT( LDBL_MAX_10_EXP  );
    COUT( FLT_ROUNDS       );
    COUT( FLT_EVAL_METHOD  );
    COUT( FLT_HAS_SUBNORM  );
    COUT( DBL_HAS_SUBNORM  );
    COUT( LDBL_HAS_SUBNORM );
}
```

EDIT: Minimal Working examples (Removed the logging but left the parsing, since I believe it is good to have he actual data from the sim)

It has been some time, since I tried different ways to work around this issue. Sadly, everything I tried didn't work out, so here I am finally following up with the minimal working example. There is one .csv file with the data from the simulation and a minimal version for both, C++ and Python. To clarify, I have the driver model and would like them to break at the same time. For this, vp, vTheta and vThetaDot should be roughly the same. As it is now, vp is 0.0825 in Pyhton and 0.00054 in C++...

minimal working examples:
accuX are constants liek 1.5
Python

```
from numpy import nan, arctan2
from csv import DictReader


class DM():
    def __init__(self):
        self.vTheta: float = nan
        self.vThetaDot: float = nan
        self.prevDistEgoToTarget: float = nan
        self.timestep: float = 0.01
        self.vpp: float = nan

    def runAccumulator(self, data):
            #storing values from previous run
            prevVTheta = self.vTheta
            
            length = 5.4
            width = 2.0

            # calculate positional data
            targetPosRear = float(data["targetPosX"]) - length/2.0 # adapt arctan2 input
            egoPosFront = float(data["egoPosX"]) + length/2.0
            distEgotoTarget = targetPosRear - egoPosFront

            # optical size target vehicle and looming
            self.vTheta = 2.0*arctan2(width,2.0*self.prevDistEgoToTarget)
            self.vEpsilon = self.vp -self.vpp

            
            self.vThetaDot = (self.vTheta - prevVTheta)/self.timestep
            self.vp = self.vThetaDot/self.vTheta 
            self.prevDistEgoToTarget = distEgotoTarget
            activationChange = (self.accuK * self.vEpsilon - self.accuM - self.accuC * prevVActivation) * self.timestep
            self.vActivation = max(0.0, prevVActivation + activationChange)
            


def main():
    with open("../log/sample.csv", 'r') as f:
        dictReader = DictReader(f)     
        listOfDict = list(dictReader)
    
    dm = DM()
    for i in range(700):
        dm.runAccumulator(listOfDict[i])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

C++ minimal working example

```
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class DM
{
private:
    /* data */
public:
    DM(/* args */);
    ~DM();
    double vTheta = std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
    double vThetaDot = std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
    double prevDistEgoToTarget = std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
    double timestep = 0.01;
    double vp = std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
    void runAccumulator(std::vector<std::string> data);

    std::ifstream sampleCSV;
    void readFileIntoString(const std::string& path);
};

DM::DM(/* args */)
{
}

DM::~DM()
{
}

void DM::runAccumulator(std::vector<std::string> data)
{
    double prevVTheta = vTheta;
    double length = 5.4;
    double width = 2.0;

    // calculate positional data
    double targetPosX = stod(data[3]) - length/2.0;
    double egoPosX = stod(data[2]) + length/2.0;
    double distEgoToTarget = targetPosX - egoPosX;

    vTheta = 2.0* std::atan2(width,distEgoToTarget);
    vThetaDot = (vTheta-prevVTheta)/timestep;
    vp = vThetaDot/vTheta;
    prevDistEgoToTarget = distEgoToTarget;
    vEpsilon = vp -vpp
    std::cout << vp << std::endl;
    auto activationChange = (accuK * vEpsilon - accuM - accuC*prevVActivation) * timestep;
    vActivation = std::max(0.0, prevVActivation + activationChange);

}

void DM::readFileIntoString(const std::string& path)
{
    this -> sampleCSV.open(path);
    if (!sampleCSV.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Could not open the file - '"
             << path << "'" << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    std::string temp;
    getline(this->sampleCSV, temp);
}

std::vector<std::string> split (std::string s, std::string delimiter) {
    size_t pos_start = 0, pos_end, delim_len = delimiter.length();
    std::string token;
    std::vector<std::string> res;

    while ((pos_end = s.find (delimiter, pos_start)) != std::string::npos) {
        token = s.substr (pos_start, pos_end - pos_start);
        pos_start = pos_end + delim_len;
        
        res.push_back(token);
    }

    res.push_back(s.substr (pos_start));
    return res;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    DM dm;
    dm.readFileIntoString("../log/sample.csv");
    std::string buffer;
    std::vector<std::string> linevec;
    
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 700; i++)
    {
        getline(dm.sampleCSV, buffer);
        linevec = split(buffer, ",");
        dm.runAccumulator(linevec);
    }
    
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

CSV: https://pastebin.com/8gBm5z8q

Comment: _floating point error is a thing, but shouldn't it be the same for both languages?_ no ... C++ can have different errors depending on the compiler being used, or even which optimizations for a compiler. So, c++ code can definitely have different FP errors than python.

Comment: You could check what happens if you remove the `arctan` calculation. The evaluation is always an approximation or table lookup. I am sure that there are some minor differences in the way Python or the C++ compilers do it. I would be curious to know, if you get the exact same round off errors if you only use +,-,*,/.

Comment: How big are the differences? Are they relevant for your application or are you just asking because you weren't expecting any differences?

Comment: It's not actually a given that either C++ implementations or Python will use IEEE floating point.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @Peter is right: *["The value representation of floating-point types is implementation-defined"](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.fundamental#8)*

Comment: @joergbrech Mhh, I did check if the arctan is the culprit and got same results. It was only 0.1 to 0.9 though, so I will try what you wrote!

Regarding the relevance: it is indeed relevant for my application, since both should brake the same way in the same situation (meaining: differences of up to 0.001 should be neglectable)

Comment: Thanks again for all the input. When saying its implementation-defined, can I do sth on my side to make sure they are the same on bith sites?

Comment: Do you get differences >0.001? If yes there is a problem with your code. Then you would need to provide a MRE as @n.m. writes to see what's going on. If no, I see no reason to do anything about it. Floating points will be floating points.

Comment: @joergbrech It is a theoretical possibility that a Python implementation and a C++ implementation on the same hardware use different floating point representations. Theory is different from practice though (in theory it shouldn't be, but in practice it is).

Comment: Short of choosing C++ compiler and Python implementations to ensure they (1) use exactly the same floating point representation and (2) the implementation of all operations (+, -, etc) and intrinsics (`atan()`, etc) work identically, then you can't get a guarantee of exact same results.  Real-world usage of floating point generally focuses on selecting algorithms to *bound* effects of propagating rounding errors through a series of calculations, not on seeking the exact same results on every platform.   Even when using only *one* programming language (since there is still platform dependence).

Comment: @n.m. please stay tuned, I am working on providing it!

Comment: (a) The C++ standard allows implementations to evaluate floating-point operations using more range and precision than their nominal type. E.g., `double` expressions can be evaluated using `long double`, as long as the result is converted to `double` when assigned or cast. Python does not have a standard or a firm specification. (b) `atan` is hard to implement and implementations typically do not provide the ideal “correctly rounded” function. Different implementations vary in the results they provide.

Comment: (c) Printing the parameters such as `DBL_DIG` tells you only about the floating-point format, not about floating-point operations, except for `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` and `FLT_ROUNDS`. A C++ implementation might use an IEEE-754 floating-point format but not conform to IEEE-754 rules for operations, such as providing correct rounding or handling subnormals properly (even if `DBL_HAS_SUBNORM` is 1).

Comment: You can find where the C++ and Python implementations first diverge by printing every calculated value to full precision. (Use the hexadecimal conversion format if available in both your C++ and Python implementations. Otherwise, use the C conversion specification `%.9999g` or equivalent.) That can reveal whether the first difference occurs in `atan` or somewhere else.

Comment: (d) Not all C++ implementations conform to the standard, and compilers have switches to select different floating-point behaviors. When providing the [mre] n. m. requested above, you should include the specific compiler version, command-line switches, and Python version used.

Comment: Unrelated: `if (log = true)` is probably not doing what you want. Just write `if (log)`, and enable compiler warnings.

Comment: @n.m. I have added the minimal working example

Comment: @EricPostpischil I have added the minimal working example, Also, I have printed with the C conversion specification, but I still don't know if it is the arctan func or the division itself, since the first place where the differenes occur is a division inside arctan func :/

Comment: @Peter, do you know how I can make sure that they use the exactly the same floating point representation and (2) the implementation of all operations ? I can use any complier and settings for both C++ and Python, but haven't figured out how to access those settings

Comment: This is as far from minimal as it gets.

Comment: @n.m. Mhh, my bad. I thought i have followed the guide. What is missing so i can fix ?

Comment: I do not see what we are to make of this alleged [mre]. The C++ code writes lines to standard output, the first of which is “0   0.01   1.399999”. The Python code writes lines to a file named `logpython.csv`, the first of which is a header and the second of which is “0.01,99.050000064074993133544921875,3.919999957084655317629540149937383830547332763671875,95.130000106990337371826171875,nan,nan,nan,”. These do not look like comparable forms of output.

Comment: Ditch all the parsing and all the logging and all the formatting. Embed hardcoded data in the code. Leave *only* computation and a single line of output.

Comment: I see what I did wrong. I will fix and update the code according to your inputs. Sorry about that. Will be updated after work (~6h)

Comment: BTW, never use `atan(y/x)`, there is `atan2`, use it instead.

Comment: @n.m. I will do that now, thank you! I just finished the minimal working example, but I am confused: I had the parsing to make it work, now that I removed everything except the core function, it won't run properly. Except if i hardcode 700*3 values...

Comment: @n.m. I have used arctan2 and fixed the minimal example by removing logging. I left the parsing of the sim data since I believe it is good to have the actual data. Otherwise, it is also possible to look at this issue by creating artificial positions of target and ego, which closer to each other,

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb, if you every find yourself in a situation, where your code does not work because of floating point arithmetic, it is very likely that at least one of the following sentences applies to you:

- You work in a very niche field of research.
- You have a bug in your code.
- You are dealing with a mathematically [ill-posed problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-posed_problem).

In your case, you have a bug in your code. Your C++ code and your Python code do not do the same thing:

- You have an index error *(you should get `targetPosX` from `data[4]` not from `data[3]`)*
- In your Python code, the second argument to the `arctan2` function is `2.0*self.prevDistEgoToTarget`, while in the C++ code it's `distEgoToTarget`.
- Your Python code does one more iteration than your C++ code.

These errors can easily be found by printing all intermediate values in just one iteration. You don't even need a debugger for this. If you fix these issues, you get a `vp` value of 0.08624797012674965 from Python and 0.086247970126749646 from C++ after 700 iterations. I would argue that the difference is negligible.

Comment: You are right. I got to focused on the issue that i lost track of the same implemantation. Thanks for pointing it out! Edit: i assume you are talking about the minimal ex specifically?

Comment: Yes, I only tried the minimal example.

Comment: So I have fixed what you have pointed out and the result is the same as you. Now I have added the successive steps, and it differs wildly again. Can you have a look at point out what I am doing wrong? I will add the lines to the minimal example. Maybe I will understand what the issue is and avoid it in the future.... @joergebrech

Comment: Have you tried what I suggested? That is printing all intermediate values of the first iteration in both implementations to a high precision and see where they first differ?

Comment: Yes, if %.9999g format is fulfilling that criteria. All values except activationChange and vActivation show no differences. vActivation is 0 until activation change is big enough, so in the first 3 iterations it stays 0 and doesn't show until later iterations. At iteration 3 activationChange differs by 0.000123899502035.

Comment: Well then %.9999g is apparently not enough. The accuracy must at least reflect the number of significant digits of IEEE-754. If after the first iteration the results of Python and C++ were exactly the same, they would also be exactly the same after every other iteration, which they obviously aren't. Now don't take this the wrong way, but I won't debug your code for you again. I feel like you should know what to do

Comment: Understandable. I will increase the accuracy and hope to find the issue myself. Thank you very much for your time and efforts, I really appreciated it. @joergbrech

Answer (score 0):

IEEE754 guarantees a few things such as:

- The format of FP values
- Basic operations (+,-,*,/ and `sqrt`) are **exact**. The result is as if you did the calculation with infinite precision, and then rounded the result.

What IEEE754 does not guarantee is that *other* functions such as `arctan` are rounded in the same way. And therefore, Python and C++ can reasonably differ by 1 ULP.

[background]
The problem with "exact rounding" is that you need an algorithm to do it correctly. For the 5 basic functions, there were well-known, efficient algorithms at the time IEEE754 was drafted. Since then, efficient algorithms have been discovered for more functions, but there are many, many functions that still do not have such algorithms. In particular, many functions still use tables and interpolation, and that's almost automatically inexact.

Comment: Just to double check my understanding: as long as I would use only +,-,* and / any two language following the IEEE 754 standard would produce the excact same results? In my case, there is the arctan which is undefined in the standard, and therefore, produces results differing by up to 1 ulp (or always excact 1 ulp?) What is ULP in the first place?

Comment: @geekygekko: ULP is "Unit in the Last Place", the last bit of the mantissa, and therefore the difference between rounding up or down. You need rounding because IEEE754 has a limited, fixed precision (53 bits for FP64). So yes, the rounding difference is always exactly one ULP, but of course the value of that ULP bit depends on the exponent. `arctan` is defined in IEEE754 mathematically, but that's with infinite precision.

Comment: @geekygekko: Also, note that rounding errors can stack. `tan(arctan(0.1))` is rounded twice, and you cannot assume those two rounding errors will cancel, or be the same between Python and C++. This is different from `(1.0/3.0)*3.0`, where again the rounding errors might not cancel. But since `/` and `*` are rounded exactly, the rounding errors will at least be consistent between all languages (assuming IEEE754)

Comment: Yes, the rounding errors stack up too much :/ still don't know what I could do to avoid that. Looking into an option, where I replace doubles with integers were possible to minimize that effect. Any other suggestions? I am also looking into libs, that use the same arctan(2) functions, like MPFR. Looking which Python lib is based on it

Comment: @geekygekko: This is a real hard problem. I would be willing to invest significant effort to sidestep the whole problem. It's not unique - we have something similar with an AI model in C++ and Python too. We've relaxed our requirements instead, to the point where we turn _off_ IEEE754 compliance.

Comment: I see. Than I will increase the efforts with the ints. Thank you for your time and help!